# How to retrieve the HTML code of a particular site's homepage

Tags: html, css

I want to get the HTML code of a particular site. It asks me to register myself first so that I can be redirected to their home page. Now, my question is: is it possible to retrieve the HTML code of the desired page just by choosing option ‘View Page Source’ which appears on right click? Is there any other way to fetch the HTML code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: http://blog.brackets.io/2013/02/11/pagesuck-brackets-extension/?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of getting the HTML source code of a page

One way, as you already know is by viewing the page's source code.
If you `Right Click -> View Page Source` or just press `Ctrl + U` you will view the source code in your browser

If you are using linux, you can use `wget` to get the source code.
Just open up a console and type `wget www.somewebsite.com` and you will get the HTML source code along with any CSS and JS links.

However, you cannot get the PHP code using any method unless you have FTP access to the server

Comment: Thanks a bunch for such a prompt response. Is there any other way of getting the template of that site online without registration of user?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of a template you are referring to but most likely no, unless you can find some kind of file like `www.somewebsite.com/template.html`

Answer (score 0):

Using any browser, the "View Page Source" option will show you the source of the page, as received by the browser (which may be different then the source currently displayed). You also have the option of using the `File > Save Page As` (or similar) menu option to save a copy of the html code of the page from the browser.

It is also possible to use command line tools like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) and [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download the page to your local machine. Those tools provide options to send data (such as cookies or headers to identify yourself) along with the request.

Comment: How to use these commands 'curl' and 'wget' in my machine? Do I need a different software to run such commands?

Comment: You will need to have either of these installed on your machine. If you have a Linux or Mac machine, you already have at least one of these installed (which one depends). It would help if we knew what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want the HTML code of a particular site's home page. My OS is Windows 8...

Comment: Installing curl/wget on windows is a tad more complicated. The reason I ask is because if you are doing this infrequently, you can just save any webpage directly from your browser (`File > Save Page As`).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible to view HTML via 'View page source'** or you could use PHP as mentioned in the comments.

> 'usign php yes php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php –
>   Vitorino fernandes'

You could also let a website and or program do it for you but it's trustability depends on the site and or program,
Do note it is **NOT** possible to view the PHP source since that is *server-side*.